# "MySQL PHP extension not available" error on one script while everything else is working fine

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

On Ubuntu 16.04 AWS instance, a WordPress website is working just fine. When I tried to install another IMS (institute management system), it failed to install and the self-installer showed the following error:

**Required - MySQL PHP extension available** (Not Available)

My php version: `7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.5`

My MySQL version: `14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

I have tried changing the `php.ini` file. 
Uncommented the line

`extension=mysql.so`

Although when I went to the location, i.e, `/usr/lib/php/20151012`, there was no file named `mysql.so`.

There was a file named `mysqli.so`, so I then changed the line to

`extension=mysqli.so`

and then restarted the apache2 service but to no avail. There is still the same error:

**Required - MySQL PHP extension available** (Not Available)

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL extension is no longer available in PHP 7.0+. If you have older code, you'll need to update or upgrade.

This is **especially** important for older WordPress installs that **will** be compromised by automatic attack tools if you're not vigilant about staying patched.

Comment: Yes, I understand but for now, I just need to install that older code. What I have gathered from looking around on the web, I need an extension file named mysql.so and it might be able to help me run that code.

Comment: But I haven't been able to figure out how do I generate that file (compiling php source etc).

Comment: If it's WordPress you really **do not** want to be installing older code. It's way too dangerous as it's likely to get attacked almost instantly and compromised if not patched and up to date.

Comment: No sir, it is not WordPress. It is another project in CodeIgniter which I need to run.

Comment: Anything that uses `mysql_query` is probably full of SQL injection holes and needs an upgrade and complete audit. Perhaps upgrading your CodeIgniter version will help.